# Помогите с написанием декоратора

Tags: python, декоратор

помогите пожалуйста написать декоратор по нижеуказанным условиям, не могу разобраться с кодом:

> Написать декоратор, который будет логировать (записывать в лог файл)
> ошибки из декорируемой функции и выбрасывать их дальше.

> - Формат лога: <имя функции> <параметры вызова> <тип ошибки> <текст ошибки>
> - Лог файл открывать каждый раз при ошибке в режиме 'a'

```
def log_errors(func):
    pass
    


- Проверить работу на следующих функциях
@log_errors
def perky(param):
    return param / 0


@log_errors
def check_line(line):
    name, email, age = line.split(' ')
    if not name.isalpha():
        raise ValueError("it's not a name")
    if '@' not in email or '.' not in email:
        raise ValueError("it's not a email")
    if not 10 <= int(age) <= 99:
        raise ValueError('Age not in 10..99 range')


lines = [
    'Имя почта@mail.ru 20',
     'имя почта@mail.ru 18'
     .....
     .....
     .....
]
for line in lines:
    try:
        check_line(line)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f'Invalid format: {exc}')
perky(param=42)
```

Comment: Виктор, рекомендую вам ознакомиться с правилами сообщества Stack Overflow на русском.

Comment: Не нашел на сайте такой вкладки, а в чем дело? Я что-то неправильно написал? Я видел здесь похожие вопросы но по другим темам, мой вопрос не повторяется, оформление тоже вроде в порядке

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, можете уточнить что по-вашему мнению не так с этим вопросом?

Comment: @MaxU, ну вот, собственно, время и ответило вопрос _что не так с вопросом_. За полгода всего 88 просмотров; вопрос не несёт в себе ничего полезного с прикладной и теоретической точек зрения. Просто кто-то помог кому-то сделать "домашку" и получил за это несколько баллов репутации. Пользы для сообщества нет, демонстрации самостоятельного поиска решения тоже нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def log_errors(func):
    def surrogate(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ZeroDivisionError as z_error:
            file_content1 = ('<{}>  <{}>  <{}>  <{}>\n'.format(func.__name__, kwargs, Exception, z_error))
            with open('function_errors.log', 'a', encoding='utf8') as file:
                file.write(file_content1)
            raise ZeroDivisionError

        except ValueError as v_error:
            file_content2 = ('<{}>  <{}>  <{}>  <{}>\n'.format(func.__name__, args, Exception, v_error))
            with open('function_errors.log', 'a', encoding='utf8') as file:
                file.write(file_content2)
            raise ValueError

    return surrogate

# Проверить работу на следующих функциях
@log_errors
def perky(param):
    return param / 0


@log_errors
def check_line(line):
    name, email, age = line.split(' ')
    if not name.isalpha():
        raise ValueError("it's not a name")
    if '@' not in email or '.' not in email:
        raise ValueError("it's not a email")
    if not 10 <= int(age) <= 99:
        raise ValueError('Age not in 10..99 range')


lines = [
    'Имя почта@mail.ru 20',
     'имя почта@mail.ru 18'
     .....
     .....
     .....
]
for line in lines:
    try:
        check_line(line)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f'Invalid format: {exc}')
perky(param=42)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть готовая библиотека - [Polog](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog). Предлагаемый там логгер универсален, его можно использовать как обычную функцию или в качестве декоратора.

Установка библиотеки:

```
$ pip install polog
```

И простой пример применения:

```
from polog import log, config, file_writer

config.add_handlers(file_writer())

@log("my message")
def function(a, b):
    return a / b

function(1, 3)
```

В консоли будет что-то похожее (актуально для версии 0.0.16):

```
[2022-10-31 22:43:58.321594] |    1    | SUCCESS |  AUTO  | "my message" | where: __main__.function() | time of work: 0.00001192 sec. | input variables: 1 (int), 3 (int) | result: 0.3333333333333333 (float)
```

Теперь попробуем спровоцировать ошибку, вызовем функцию с аргументами, которые приведут к делению на 0:

```
function(1, 0)
```

И на этот раз в консоли будет что-то вот такое:

```
[2022-10-31 22:46:03.772676] |    2    |  ERROR  |  AUTO  | "my message" | where: __main__.function() | time of work: 0.00001192 sec. | input variables: 1 (int), 0 (int) | local variables: a = 1 (int), b = 0 (int) | exception: ZeroDivisionError("division by zero") | traceback: return a / b (".../some_file.py", line 7, in function)
```

Более подробно о возможностях библиотеки читайте в [документации](https://github.com/pomponchik/polog) (на русском).